# AnyLogic Computer Processor Advice needed - Single-core speed vs. number of cores?

Tags: anylogic

I model on an ancient PC and recently got some lab funds for a new modeling computer. The choice of processor confounds me. For optimal AnyLogic simulation modeling, should I focus on maxing out the single-core speed or max the number of processor cores? Also, would a high-end graphics card help? I have heard from my engineering colleagues that for certain modeling tools that they do help with the work load. Any advice helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what AnyLogic answered when I asked for the perfect computer to buy:

> The recommended platform for AnyLogic is a powerful PC/laptop running
> 64-bit operating system (Windows preferable), plus CPU with multiple
> cores like i7 and at least 8 Gb of RAM.
>
> In general, faster CPU (3GHz or more recommended) means faster single
> run execution. More cores means faster execution of the experiments
> running the model multiple times in parallel (optimization, parameter
> variation, monte carlo, etc.). Also, pedestrians and transporters
> benefit from many cores (even single run, since the algorithm causing
> movement of pedestrians and transporters uses all available cores).
> For the time being, AnyLogic doesn't support GPU processing. RAM is
> crucial when you have a lot of agents and many parallel runs (e.g. if
> single run takes 1GB, then 8 parallel runs will take 8 Gb). For
> working with GIS map, it may be needed to have a good connection to
> the Internet. For example, if model requests a lot of routes from
> online route provider.
>
> On average, a middle-end PC/laptop in sufficient for most of the
> models, high-end PC or server/instance will be useful in case of
> really heavy models.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Felipe's reply: graphic card is completely irrelevant, AnyLogic does not support outsourcing computations to their tensor cores.

Focus on decent processor speed and 8-12 cores as well as at least 16 GB of RAM and (crucial!!) an SSD harddrive. Good to go :)

Oh, and you may want to use Windows. Linux and Mac OS seem to feature more problems/bugs in AnyLogic than Windows